# Is there any practical difference between accessing attributes and methods throught @staticmethod or @classmethod?

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, class-method

I understand that static methods are meant to perform operations that do not access methods or attributes within the same class. They simply perform specific operations that do not need the class reference, like building a string with a certain pattern, for example. Class methods, on the other hand, are meant to access methods and attributes of its own class.

However, is there any practical difference between accessing methods/attributes through a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`? See the two constructions below.

Getting/Setting via `@staticmethod`

```
class Foo:

    bar= 1

    @staticmethod
    def set_bar_static(val):
        Foo.bar = val
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_bar_static(val):
        return Foo.bar
```

Getting/Setting via `@classmethod`

```
class Foo:

    bar= 1

    @classmethod
    def set_bar(cls, val):
        cls.bar= val

    @classmethod
    def get_bar(cls, val):
        return cls.bar
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance could mess things up.

Comment: How? Could you please expand on that?

Comment: *Any* inheritance could change the meaning. Your static method refers, well, statically to the class `Foo`.  The class method `Foo.set_bar`, called from a subclass of `Foo`, sets an attribute on the calling class, not `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense @chepner! But if I don't have any inheritance, then these two would behave the same, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between staticmethod and classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

Comment: You don't have inheritance *now*. Pretend someone else defined a subclass of `Foo` named `Bar`. Do you think they would want `Bar.set_bar(3)` to set `Foo.bar` or `Bar.bar`?